# Why didn't Vietnam agree to host a military base for the United States?

Tags: united-states, china, vietnam

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_United_States_military_bases#/media/File:American_bases_worldwide.svg

I was looking at this map and noticed that the U.S. doesn't have a military base in Vietnam.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States%E2%80%93Vietnam_relations

> The annual Bilateral Human Rights Dialogue resumed in 2006 after a
> two-year hiatus. The U.S. and Vietnam signed a Bilateral Trade
> Agreement in July 2000, which went into force in December 2001. In
> 2003, the two countries signed a Counternarcotics Letter of Agreement
> (amended in 2006), a Civil Aviation Agreement, and a textile
> agreement. In January 2007, Congress approved Permanent Normal Trade
> Relations (PNTR) for Vietnam. In July 2015, the United States hosted
> Vietnamese Communist Party General Secretary Nguyễn Phú Trọng in the
> first-ever visit of a Vietnamese Communist Party General Secretary to
> the United States following a concerted effort by the Obama
> administration to pursue warmer relations with Vietnam.[40]

Despite Obama's effort to pursue warmer relations with Vietnam, it seems that Vietnam has yet to host an American military base within its own soil despite increasing tensions between China and Vietnam over the South China Sea? Why won't Vietnam seek a closer military ties with the United States given that Vietnam cannot ensure its own security against a much stronger China just like South Korea and Japan?

Comment: The US has bases in 85 countries according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_United_States_military_bases) - this is a lot, but less than half. Why do you assume every other country should have a US base?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Obviously the Vietnam war legacy makes military cooperation a much more touchy issue than opening or enhancing US-Vietnam trade relations.

A quick search finds that there [were](https://www.brookings.edu/blog/order-from-chaos/2022/12/20/a-window-of-opportunity-to-upgrade-us-vietnam-relations/) even a couple of US aircraft carrier visits to Vietnamese ports in the past few years. But permanent military bases are probably a bridge too far, especially since the China-Vietnam disputes seem to relate mostly to [tiny] islands.

---

The legacy I'm talking about isn't limited to the physical impact that the war had on Vietnam and how that is remembered (it's called the "War of Resistance against America" over there), but also to the fact that the faction that won was the Soviet supported one. Nowadays Vietnam is still a one-party state, with an official Marxist ideology. While they've opened their economic system somewhat, and send a large number of students to the US, in other regards they are still very much closer to China, and rejecting most other kinds of US influence (in particular almost anything having to do with democracy or [Western conception of] human rights) [e.g.](https://thediplomat.com/2023/01/anti-american-propaganda-in-vietnam/)

> Nguyen Phu Trong, the first general secretary of the CPV to visit the White House in 2015, when the two countries celebrated the 25th anniversary of normalized diplomatic ties, was also the first foreign leader to pay a visit to China in 2022, after Xi Jinping secured an unprecedented third term as the head of the Chinese Communist Party.  In a joint declaration issued during the visit, both committed to wrestle with external challenges, including “color revolutions” and “criticism of their human rights records.”

Also, foreigners in Vietnam, especially those from the US are still regarded with a lot of suspicion, and subject to surveillance:

> Quang, whose NGO derives funding largely from U.S. donors, is in charge of dealing with documents for foreign visitors, including reporting to the CPV Central Committee’s Commission for External Relations regarding what they do each given day, where they stay, and what they say. He said that American experts who come to Vietnam on business visas are subject to more scrutiny than other Western visitors.
>
> “Usually it takes us more time to get approval for American guests,” said Quang.

Although prosecutions against students involved in US programs is relatively rare, it does happen sometimes, e.g. some

> were charged with “propaganda against the State of the Socialist Republic of Vietnam” and “abusing democratic freedoms to infringe upon the interests of the State… with a view to overthrowing the people’s administration.”

Likewise, the US is not officially included in Vietnam's list of 14 "strategic partners", which include at least China, India, and Russia (although I don't have a full list). The more recently expanded version of that list [seems](https://thediplomat.com/2022/04/why-vietnam-holds-the-trump-card-in-the-u-s-vietnam-partnership/) to have 17 countries, including Australia and Japan, but not the US.

Comment: I dunno how big these islands are compared to Snake Island, but the recent experience of that conflict shows that bases/troops on such small islands are hard to defend in modern war, even by the side with a vastly superior navy.

Comment: There is an obvious difference between Vietnam and other countries where the US has military bases: the latter are either former wartime allies or defeated wartime enemies.  It might be worthwhile to mention this explicitly rather than obliquely; the legacy of the Vietnam war may not be obvious to all readers.

Comment: Also it should be kept in mind that Vietnam is still communistic country.

Comment: The US probably remembers that in 1979, when USSR is planning to build a military base in Vietnam, the US prompted the Chinese (wordlessly) to attack Vietnam in order to force USSR to change its mind.